# Rails error says cannot find a certain partial template, but I did not define any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partials, cocoon-gem

Using the better_error gem, I get the following error

```
Missing partial recipes/_ingredient_fields, application/_ingredient_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}.
```

It's saying that it cannot locate my **_ingredient_fields.html.haml** file under recipes, but I did not create such file. I did create another partial that is under the name of **_ingredients_fields.html.haml**, and did use that in the code.

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: {multipart: true} do |f|

    # some other code here....

    .row
        .col-md-6
            %h3 Ingredients
            #ingredients
                = f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient|
                    = render 'ingredients_fields', f: ingredient
                .links
                    #complaining about this line, but i did not use any partial in this line.
                    = link_to_add_association "Add Ingredients", f, :ingredients, class: "btn btn-default add-button"
    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Been stuck for a while, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there is `_ingredients_firelds.html.haml` spelling mistake and you are rendering `= render 'ingredients_fields', f: ingredient` so change your page name to `_ingredients_fields.html.haml`

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad on my part. The spellings actually match in the actual files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the **_ingredients_firelds.html.haml** above is a typo, so you have a file named _ingredients_fields.html.haml under /views/recipes/, try adding recipes folder to the path like this:

```
= render '/recipes/ingredients_fields', f: ingredient
```

You may also have a typo in your code.

EDIT: Ah I see you are using a cocoon gem.  So rename your _ingredients_fields.html.haml to ingredient_fields.html.haml. Coocon expects you to have a Ingredient model class, so use singular here.

Comment: I found the solution, but it is a weird one. If you know why it is, please comment on my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I can ONLY use `_ingredient_fields.html.erb` as my partial name. I tried a lot of other variations, and all of them return errors. The only explanation that I can come up with is that this is built in to the cocoon gem.

Comment: Yeah, you beat me to it, I was writing my answer while you posted your findings ;)